# How long is a crewed vehicle a creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Its my turn: I crew a vehicle with a creature meaning it becomes a creature artefact and I attack with it.

Now on the opponents turn my opponent has a enchantment which targets creatures (e.g. -3 to all my creatures). Does my vehicle now count as a creature or just an artefact?

Comment: Every Vehicle in the game except one has a reminder text that crewing lasts until end of turn. Is it unclear to you what "end of turn" means?

Comment: no, I just did not read properly then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the vehicle stops being a creature at the end of your turn.

> **702.121a** Crew is an activated ability of Vehicle cards. “Crew N” means “Tap any number of untapped creatures you control with total power N
>   or greater: This permanent becomes an artifact creature until end of
>   turn.”

This is reflected in the reminder text most Vehicle cards have beside their Crew ability.

If you activate the Crew ability again on your opponent's turn, it will again become a creature and potentially be affected by the enchantment.

[Source](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Crew)